# Row number generation in Hive

Tags: hive

```
SELECT distinct concat ('0030','|',ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY acctnumber ORDER BY acctnumber)) 
    FROM customer
```

When I execute the above query to get the row sequence for each it gives invalid column reference number.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I was able to fix it....